# Lack of skin in a certain area of the body --- hypo[what]?

Tags: terminology

Lack of skin in a certain area of the body. How shell I name this?

- Hypocutaneousis?
- Hypo[somethingElse]?

What is the correct term?

Comment: Exactly what are you referring to? A permanent lack of skin in an area sounds like a permanantly open wound to me.

Comment: I mean to a partial lack of skin, like when someone has too little skin after bad surgery or after an accident (I'm not aware of diseases that will reduce the amount of three-layers skin).

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not an area where I have any education or experience. However, out of curiosity I consulted google and found two genetic castle diseases that should be relevant to your question:

- [Epitheliogenesis imperfecta](http://vetbook.org/wiki/cow/index.php?title=Epitheliogenesis_imperfecta) (vetbook.org)
- [Ectodermal dysplasia](http://vetbook.org/wiki/cow/index.php?title=Ectodermal_dysplasia)

Both diseases are very serious, and Epitheliogenesis imperfecta is fatal (due to infections).

I chose not to include any pictures of the diseases in this answer since they often look quite horrible, and some people might find them unsettling. If you click the links there are pictures of the conditions though.

A "similar" condition in humans might be  [Epidermolysis bullosa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidermolysis_bullosa), which is caused by decreased anchoring between dermis and epidermis, which cause a very fragile skin:

> Epidermolysis bullosa (EB) is a group of mainly inherited connective tissue diseases that cause blisters in the skin and mucosal membranes, with an incidence of 20 per million newborns in the United States.[1] It is a result of a defect in anchoring between the epidermis and dermis, resulting in friction and skin fragility. Its severity ranges from mild to lethal.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score -1):

You can say skin atrophy or just thinning where dermal thickness is reduced.

https://m.iliveok.com/health/skin-atrophy_77524i15941.html

Comment: Thinness does not seem to be the same thing as the OP's question about lack of skin.

Comment: @kmm what can I say but the question is unclear but being a specialist physician for 40 years my answer is likely correct for most instances.